# Article usage with "European society"

Tags: grammar, articles

I wonder if in a sentence "He feels privileged to be a part of **the** European society", the usage of the definite article is correct. On one hand, "society" is a mass noun, but here it's about a specific group of people.

Comment: It depends on what you mean by your sentence. With "the", my question would be "Which European society?"

Comment: The use of the definite article could work in the right context. You haven't provided more than a single sentence. What sentences came before it?

Comment: Obviously, with the comparable 'the gay community', the article is used. I suppose the article reinforces the idea of unity. 'European society' has a subtly different meaning from 'the European society'; non-count 'society' has always at least strongly connoted 'moneyed classes' etc.